# Combinatorics: Getting as many elements while keeping loss per loss type low

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I have a whole bunch of elements. Each element has a different, but certain types of losses (as in mathematical optimisation) which can be expressed as floats. I would like as many elements as possible (selecting many elements is good), but such that I have as little loss as possible - both overall and per loss type. So if I have two types of losses the scenario {mean loss type A = 1, mean loss type B = 1} is better than the scenario {mean loss type A = 0.1, mean loss type B = 1.8}. To get this those more homogeneous losses I am willing to trade overall loss or having less elements.

An example to get some intuition might be: I have a large pool of cars and I want to get as many cars as possible. However they have different kinds of costs and advantages: Money to pay, horse power, size of space for luggage, speed. I don't mind is if one cars is great and the rest I select is mediocre. But what I don't want is to only have a lot of overall horse power and no overall size of space for luggage. So I am looking not for a balance among the cars I select, but a balance among the properties of the cars. Although I want a lot of cars, I don't want bad cars, so I'd rather have a car less than a bad one.

For getting the homogeneity I think I have to look in the direction of either mean squared error or harmonic mean, instead of a simple arithmetic mean.

Selecting the right elements I think I am dealing with a combinatorial problem or an discrete optimisation problem or something like that.

If someone has an idea for implementation: I am using python.

Comment: It seems like a combinatorial problem to me. The difficulty, I think, will be in finding a common unit to measure each of the different parameters; you need to come up with some kind of cost function that is able to weigh up each of these params in a common unit. Beyond that, you'll need to then select some kind of heuristic - there's loads e.g. see [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) and the "Related methods" section.

Comment: Also, wouldn't the best solution converge on just owning a single, extremely good car? What's the limiting criteria there?

Comment: @roganjosh: No, I should not end up with one car, because I would have to add the reciprocal of the number of cars as a loss: More cars is better.

Comment: True but I think it will also depend on the distribution of properties within your samples. "Although I want a lot of cars, I don't want bad cars, so I'd rather have a car less than a bad one." is not a hard-and-fast objective so the heuristic could behave very differently for different problems (in terms of the pool of cars you present it with).

Comment: It might actually be easier with a genetic algorithm so that you can keep evaluating the populations, rather than something like sim. annealing. Still, you have an interesting and undoubtedly complex problem on your hands

Comment: Sorry to keep adding comments, I'm still thinking about this one :) I think GA is definitely superior to something like sim. annealing. The reason being that SA almost certainly _could_ end up with a single car. That's because there are minor state changes on each iteration and the current and future state are the only thing being evaluated. In that case, in a series of many small steps, your pool could get cut right down if there's enough variation in the features of your data. GA will at least allow you to evaluate many solutions as a whole.

Comment: @roganjosh: No problem. I am very thankful for your thoughts. Can you point me to an implementation in Python for GA? How about the formulation of the loss function - especially how to get the balance right (see my thought about harmonic mean / root mean squared loss) - any thought on that? Actually I think my problem is rather generic - is it not? - sounding even like a paper... I am surprised there is no solution to that already (not surprised that I don't know it though).

Comment: I believe there are two objectives: max items, min max of costs. The min of the max of the costs (losses) will make sure all losses are close. To get proven optimal solutions, I think this can be formulated as a MIP problem. I would solve a number of different problems to be able to plot the trade offs between the two objectives.

Comment: @Make42 I had the same thought, but then consider something on a more simple scale. You have 25 numbers randomly distributed between 0 and 100; how would you _objectively_ determine which cluster of numbers had the best balance between the mean and variance, as well as having the largest possible cluster? It's just a spread of numbers, and you have three independent metrics in which to "solve" the problem. Whatever way you tune the relative weight of the three criteria, you'll probably get blown out by the RNG if you ran the whole thing again. It seems a sound premise, I'm just not sure it is.

Comment: In regards to your first question, you might try [this](https://github.com/DEAP/deap) (never used it) or build a GA yourself following [this](http://lethain.com/genetic-algorithms-cool-name-damn-simple/) tutorial. You can have one built in a day or two, heuristics are _much_ easier to build than, say, an ANN, as they have a relatively simple core and once you understand the basics of that core you can very quickly make it more elaborate. So you can prototype and see if the idea has legs before investing more time.